# Secure Jupyter Notebook in Gcloud

Tags: jupyter-notebook, gcp-ai-platform-notebook, gcp-notebook

I set up a jupyter notebook on GCP following the tutorial here: https://towardsdatascience.com/running-jupyter-notebook-in-google-cloud-platform-in-15-min-61e16da34d52

I can successfully run a notebook but  I have the warnings:
WARNING: The notebook server is listening on all IP addresses and not using encryption. This is not recommended.
WARNING: The notebook server is listening on all IP addresses and not using authentica
tion. This is highly insecure and not recommended.

How am I able to get rid of these warning? They appear in the tutorial as well, I would just rather not have them so I can be secure.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using GCP's new [AI Platform Notebooks](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform-notebooks/) instead?  You can create a new environment in seconds and it's designed to be secure by default.

You won't have to worry about any of the above warnings :)

Comment: Great idea @Zain. Thanks for sharing!